# How can I figure out if the authenticated user is authorized to access an area/controller/action?

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Being in a view and you know the area-name, controller-name and action-name of a destination to which you want the user to provide a link to, how can I figure out if the area/controller/action is authorized for the authenticated user.

Imaginary Use-case:

I have a table with a list of books (the result of bookscontroller.index). To the far right are some icons to edit or delete a specific book. The edit link refers to bookscontroller.edit and the delete link to bookscontroller.delete.

On the actions there are custom authorizationattributes and this works perfect. If a user want to access books/edit/1 and the user is not allowed to edit books, the user gets redirected to the logon page.

It is a bit stupid to have that edit-icon there if the user is not allowed to edit books. So at view level I would like to be able to figure out if the user is allowed to use the edit action of the bookscontroller. If he is, show the icon if not, do not show the action.

Goal: use that knowledge to create a custom tag-helper.

Answer (score 0):

The go-to method is reactive, i.e. you check if a user can do action when the user tries to do. Since you do not want to go that way, here is how. (yet, this is anti-pattern)

Have the authentication token of the user send back to backend. The backend should have an API end point for each button on the page user can click. With the authentication token, the back-end resolve whether to dim or enable the buttons.

Now, what the backend does to resolve this is not very efficient. The backend needs to literally attempt certain actions and aborts the transaction. For create and retrieve, it is trivial (you can pre-resolve them) but for edit and delete, this requires a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of controlling such actions on UI is to use role based authorization.
For the buttons or other such UI elements, setup role tags, e.g. "admin:edit", "viewer:readonly" etc.
When you are authenticating a user, send the applicable roles from the backend server, store them in a way that is globally accessible to your UI and use them for filtering UI elements across your application.